# What is the difference between disk mapping and disk mounting? When are these methods applied?

Tags: networking, virtual-machine, disk, san

I am new to networking and I wish to know the differences between

```
    1) Disk mapping
    2) Disk mounting
```

When to use these methods. I could not get a clear understanding from the existing online resources, please can someone explain in a layman's term. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Disk Mapping is a virtual drive map for a shared folder.

Disk Mounting is a physical hard drive insertion to your system.

Comment: So mapping is making a folder appear as a drive, and mounting is making a drive appear as a folder?